# Getting Attachments from QC

Tags: hp-quality-center

Is there any tool available that can export attachments from QC?
I already have a tool for exporting test cases from QC  to Excel, but that doesn't solve the attachement issue.

Comment: You can use OTA api or if you are above version 11.0 you can directly download using rest http request. Depending upon your storage need you can write code to put those file under your storage location.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your repository is setup, you may be able to log into the file system and find the name of the file, I usually try and go by the exact date/time of the file I am looking for.

After QC10 everything went to the hard drive, where as before you could set it up to store the attachments in the database. If you select your project in the Site Projects tab (Siteadmin area) and look on right side, if you see there a path to the repository then you can look there (or you will see it is saved to the database).

However, I'm not aware of being able to automatically put it into Excel as an object (if you are specifically looking for that).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the REST API:

```
https://HOST/qcbin/rest/domains/DOMAIN/projects/PROJECT/defects/{DEFECT_ID}/attachments/{ATTACHMENT_NAME}
```

or you can generate a report that will include attachments through the Dashboard->Analysis View.

the second option will be easier.